# Threads Error (Is not Applicable)

Tags: java

```
public class B implements Runnable{
    public void run(){}
}

class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread m = new Thread();
        Thread m1 = new Thread("B");
        Thread m2 = new Thread(new B());
        Thread m3 = new Thread("B",new B());
    }
}
```

Why am i receiving an error on the last thread object "m3". This is the error I am getting:

```
constructor Thread.Thread(Runnable,AccessControlContext) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Runnable)
constructor Thread.Thread(ThreadGroup,Runnable) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to ThreadGroup)
constructor Thread.Thread(ThreadGroup,String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to ThreadGroup)
constructor Thread.Thread(Runnable,String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Runnable)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output 
1 error
```

Comment: How about `m3 = new Thread(new B(), "B");` ?

Comment: That worked... But why does the order matter?

Comment: Order matters in most languages. Say you have a function of the type `function(String a, String b)`  - without any ordering the strings would get mixed up.